# Changing arrays that users can change

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry in advance if i am saying some weird things, i'm new to php.

In some code (which won't show correctly if i would try to put it on stackoverflow) I want a user to be able to change some variables given in an array. However, I notice that if the user changes this variable, the variable changes back to what is was said to be in the array mentioned earlier. Does it indeed work like this, or does the array stay changed whenever a user trys to change it?

The user can change the array by typing their changes into an input field, which says that `$Password['0'] = $_POST['InputFromTheUser']` (again, if i woudl try to paste the ful lcode here stackoverflow wont take it)

Am i making a mistake or is there simply no way to change an array?

Edit:
Here is the code

```
    $ANaam = array("Wildhoven","van Boven","de Groot","van den Bent","Admin");//Maar als de array is aangepast wrod de array weer terug aangepast odmat hier iets staat. Er meot dus een manier zijn om deze array aan te passen
    $Adres = array("Langlaan 1","Kortlaan 1","Breedlaan 1","LerarenkamerSMC","Admin");
    $Postcode = array("2212GJ","8263SJ","1293OP","0000AA","Admin");
    $Stad = array("Leiden","Delft","Voorschoten","Voorburg","Admin");
    $Email = array("Marja@hotmail.nl","Kees@hotmail.nl","Hanna@hotmail.nl","bnt@st-maartenscollege.nl","Admin");
    $Telefoonnummer = array("06 1234567","06 1110001","097","06 1098901","Admin");

    $_SESSION["VNARRAY"] = $VNaam;
    $_SESSION["ANARRAY"] = $ANaam;
    $_SESSION["ADARRAY"] = $Adres;
    $_SESSION["POARRAY"] = $Postcode;
    $_SESSION["STARRAY"] = $Stad;
    $_SESSION["EMARRAY"] = $Email;
    $_SESSION["TEARRAY"] = $Telefoonnummer; 

    $IDG = $_SESSION["IDvanGebruiker"];
    ?> 
<h1>
      Uw TechN account
    </h1>
    <!-- Naam van klant -->
    <br>
    <p>
      Gebruikersnaam: <?php echo $_SESSION["GNARRAY"]["$IDG"]; ?> <form method="post" action=""> <input type="text" name="AnderGN"> <input type="submit" name="AanpassenGN" value="aanpassen">
    </p>
<?php if(isset($_POST['AanpassenGN']) && !empty($_POST["AnderGN"])){ $_SESSION["GNARRAY"]["$IDG"] = $_POST["AnderGN"];  header("Refresh:0"); }  ?>
    <p>
      Wachtwoord: <?php echo $_SESSION["WWARRAY"]["$IDG"];  ?><form method="post" action=""> <input type="text" name="AnderWW"> <input type="button" name="AanpassenWW" value="aanpassen">
    </p>
<?php ?>
    <p>
      Voornaam: <?php echo $_SESSION["VNARRAY"]["$IDG"];  ?> <form method="post" action=""> <input type="text" name="AnderVN"> <input type="submit" name="AanpassenVN" value="aanpassen">
    </p>
<?php  if(isset($_POST['AanpassenVN']) && !empty($_POST["AnderVN"])){ $_SESSION["VNARRAY"]["$IDG"] = $_POST["AnderVN"]; $VNaam["$IDG"] = $_POST["AnderVN"];  header("Refresh:0"); }?>
```

Some of the words used are in dutch, as I am dutch.

Comment: Could you please try to make a minimal reproducible example after all? Please note that PHP is inherently _stateless_, every page load starts from a blank slate. If you want user input to _persist_ you would need to somehow save and preserve it between page loads.

Comment: `try to paste the ful lcode here stackoverflow wont take it`  - yes it will, you need to indent it at least 4 spaces  see - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: change this `$POST_['InputFromTheUser']` to `$_POST['InputFromTheUser']`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Sorry, typo.

Comment: In your code you have several form open tags `<form ... >` but no closing tags `</form>` also each form is submitted as a separate request to the server.  Values in `$_POST` only exist when a form is submitted (in this case). They are not magically transported from the client to the server just because they are in an input field.  But that is just based on the code I see above.

Comment: If that is indeed the case, then you should look up "form submissions in PHP" , and the "client/server  relationship", and "statelessness of HTTP".  You can just google these(probably). Hope it helps you to understand how it all works.

Comment: Is `$IDG` an array index?

Comment: @tshimkus yes everytime someone logs in the $IDG becomes the place in the arrays that that users information is in.